# Выравнивание блоков по центру родительского

Tags: html, css

Есть такая структура `HTML`:

```css
.listOfProperties {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.listOfProperties li {
  font-size: 27.5px;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.listOfProperties li:hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.listOfProperties li img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-buttons">
  <ul class="listOfProperties">
    <li class="withdraw"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>WITHDRAW</span></li>
    <li class="servise"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>RULES OF SERVISE</span></li>
    <li class="settings"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>SETTINGS</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы было как на картинке при наведении на какой-то из элементов списка (то есть опустить в центр картинку и надпись). Подскажите пожалуйста, как так можно выровнять? Ничего не смог найти относительно этого(буду признателен и за литературу)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для li можно использовать 
display: flex;
align-items: center;

```css
.listOfProperties {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.listOfProperties li {
  font-size: 27.5px;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.listOfProperties li:hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.listOfProperties li img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-buttons">
  <ul class="listOfProperties">
    <li class="withdraw"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>WITHDRAW</span></li>
    <li class="servise"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>RULES OF SERVISE</span></li>
    <li class="settings"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>SETTINGS</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: именно то, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `display` и `align-items`. И добавить класс к нужным вам частям

```css
.listOfProperties {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.listOfProperties li {
  font-size: 27.5px;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.listOfProperties li:hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.listOfProperties li img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.vertical {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-buttons">
  <ul class="listOfProperties">
    <li class="vertical withdraw"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>WITHDRAW</span></li>
    <li class="vertical servise"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>RULES OF SERVISE</span></li>
    <li class="vertical settings"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><span>SETTINGS</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```